# Unsupported URL error for a cdvfile://

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, cordova-plugin-file

**Problem:**

In my app, I want to access an image through cordova wkwebview.
The HTML element looks as follows.

```
<img src="cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/MyFolder/file.jpg">
```

While loading this, I get error "Failed to load resource: unsupported URL".
I am working with iOS 10.2.

**Things verified/tried:**

If list of files present in "cordova.file.dataDirectory" under folder "MyFolder" is checked, I do see the "file.jpg" present there. It has the native URL as 
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/app_id/Library/NoCloud/MyFolder/file.jpg.

I have added "img-src 'self' cdvfile: " to the Content-Security-Policy.

I have added following in the config.xml

```
<access origin="cdvfile://*" /> 
<allow-navigation href="cdvfile://*" /> 
<allow-intent href="cdvfile://*" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
```

There are no special (non-ASCII) characters in the URL as mentioned in threads relating to this error.
What else could be the reason of "Unsupported URL"?.

Is the way I am accessing cdvfile:// path incorrect?

**Update**

I came across a link (forgot to capture that) saying the webview needs relative path and hence cdvfile:// would not work. I tried to change the image source to a relative path by changing it to "../../../../../../../../..//var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/app-id/Library/NoCloud/MyFolder/file.jpg" and I could now see a new error - "Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"

I could get the image working by "reading" the contents of the file and passing that base64 data as image source. But that is not how it should be, should it?

Comment: yes, accessing cdvfile:// path is incorrect practice. because browser doesn't understand cdvfile:// protocol.

Comment: Do you mean https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#cdvfile-protocol section is incorrect?

Comment: What is the right way of achieving this? Should I read the data in the file and assign that to the image using data://?

Comment: my bad. haven't checked after update.
have you added Content-Security-policy rules ? as they mentioned there ?

Comment: Yes, I have done that, since that document gave me this clue of using cdvfile.

Comment: I have the same issue....

Comment: @DaigoSato Is there anything else that you have tried? If so, you can mention that to further reduce the scope of problem.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @DarkNeuron - Not really. cdvfile:// does not work with WKWebView - check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10141
Only two ways known to get this working
1. Create a local http server and use http://localhost
2. Read the file contents in base64 format and use that as src.

I know both are really horrible options, but thats what I know as of today.

Comment: I ran into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546965/why-is-my-ios-app-rejecting-cdvfile-and-file-links Haven't made it work yet, but I'm hopeful.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you would be running a webserver in your app? Keep posted.

Answer (score 6):

If you use the newest ios platform (cordova-ios@6.x.x) you can use the scheme and host name options:

```xml
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

Then you should get and use the **schemeUrl** (`app://`) instead of the `cdvfile://` or `file://` url.

```js
var cdvfileUrl = "cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/MyFolder/file.jpg";

// Convert to native url
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cdvfileUrl, function(entry) {
    var nativeUrl = entry.toNativeURL(); // will be "file://...."

    // Use nativeUrl to get scheme friendly url
    var schemeUrl = window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(nativeUrl);  // Will be "app://..."
});
```

You can use this schemeUrl in your your `<img>` src tag.

Comment: I got deprecation warnings with `toNativeURL` but just `toURL` worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Future reference, with the latest WKWebView, the direct setting of the src attribute fails.

Only way I've found to load the image is something like this:

```
    function loadImageFromFile(filename, imgElement) {
        // filename is cdvfile:....... (string)
        // imgElement is target IMG element name (string)
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filename, function success(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                    if (reader.result) {
                        var elem = document.getElementById(imgElement);
                        var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(reader.result)], { type: "image/png" });
                        elem.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
                    }
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            });
        }, function () {
            console.log("File not found: ");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WKWebView, there is only option that you setup a local http web server and then access it via http://localhost ...

Unfortunately "cdvfile" does not works for WKWebView.