# Ionic 3 - ImgCache.js failed to load resource: unsupport URL in iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've managed to get imagecache.js working in my Ionic 3 project, based on the tutorial in this link: https://medium.com/ninjadevs/caching-images-ionic-ccf2f4ca8d1f.

When I run `ionic serve`, the images will download and cache and load properly, however when I install the app on my iOS device, the images fail to load and when I inspect it in my Safari browser, I'm seeing these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: unsupported URL

cdvfile://localhost/persistent/imgcache/a001f5f745d1d28d42b3395dd83d408a26aa9e6b.jpg
```

In my `config.xml` file, I have the following entries, which I believed would solve the problem but haven't:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Has anyone else run into a similar issue?

Comment: not entirely related to the question, but you can use [this module](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader) to catch images on your app. I'm using it and works great on both android and ios.

Comment: This is awesome, I've been trying it out! Though when I enable debug mode and inspect the app running on my iOS device through the safari inspector, I'm getting a File Transfer error with a code of 3. The images still load, but I'm not sure if it's pulling them from the cache or it's just redownloading them every time

Comment: Try by setting the the return type of cached images: `this.imageLoaderConfig.setImageReturnType('base64');`. That should fix the issue. Another way to test if the plugin is working is to add some super heavy images and see if they're loaded almost instantaneously.

Comment: I am running in to this same issue. Did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to fix loading of images cached with ImgCache.js under WKWebView.

1. Add this line to config.xml:

```
    <platform name="ios">
        <!-- Line here under iOS settings -->
        <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

2. Use next code to normalize URL loaded from ImgCache.js:

```
    private normalizeUrl(url: string) {
        let result = url;

        const cdvfilePrefix = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/imgcache/';
        if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() && url.indexOf(cdvfilePrefix) === 0 ) {
            result = this.getIosImgCacheDirectoryUrl() + url.split(cdvfilePrefix)[1]
        }

        if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            result = result.replace(/^file:\/\//g, '');
        }

        return result;
    }

    private getIosImgCacheDirectoryUrl(): string {
        return cordova.file.dataDirectory.split('Library')[0] + 'Library/files/imgcache/';
    }
```

3. After that use it on the cachedUrl

```
      ImgCache.getCachedFileURL(src,
            (originalUrl, cacheUrl) => {
              const localUrl = this.normalizeUrl(cacheUrl);
              // now you can use it for <img src="{{localUrl}}>
            });
```

The resulting URL on iOS will be something like:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<UUID>/Library/files/imgcache/<UNIQUE_FILE_ID>
```

Note that it **must start with /**, not with cdvfile://, nor file://, nor http://localhost:8080/, nor anything else

Comment: Any chance anyone has a non ionic pure Cordova basedq solution for this issue?

Comment: @user2841639 As you can see, I've just debugged the code, found the url that it generates and replaced it with the one it should be. You can try the same approach as me, but instead do what is needed for your particular case in the normalizeUrl method. Otherwise it should be very similar, no matter if it's Cordova or Ionic. You should get the same resulting URL as I provided for iOS at the end

Comment: the solution of @afrish works, only need to apply `src = src.replace(/^file:\/\//g, '');` on img url returned by imgcache.js.
Another solution is to use window.URL.createObjectURL to get a DOM string for the Blob image, well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63590113/4982169)